# Dynamic Nested Blocks for modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I would like to create a module for the Azure Application Gateway.

I want to disable some rule groups with the inline block disabled_rule_group, but how can I make this configurable in the module? This should be a optional variable.

I found the `for_each` for the nested blocks.

Example:

```hcl
variable "disabled_rule_groups" {
  default     = [
    {
      rule_group_name = "REQUEST-931-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RFI"
      rules           = [
        931100,
        931130]
    },
    {
      rule_group_name = "REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI"
      rules           = [
        942100
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```hcl
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "AppGateway" {
  dynamic "disabled_rule_group" {
    for_each = [var.disabled_rule_groups]
    content {
      rule_group_name = disabled_rule_group.value.rule_group_name
      rules           = disabled_rule_group.value.rules
    }
  }
}
```

This is not working however.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix the syntax?

Additionally, the variable `disabled_rule_groups` should be optional. So if no disabled_rule_groups is set the block should be disabled.
How can i achieve this? Do i need a second boolean variable and a if in the for each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the syntax you have there is incorrect. You apparently mean this:

```hcl
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "AppGateway" {
  dynamic "disabled_rule_group" {
    for_each = var.disabled_rule_groups // Removed [ ] from this line.
    content {
      rule_group_name = disabled_rule_group.value.rule_group_name
      rules           = disabled_rule_group.value.rules
    }
  }
}
```

> Additionally, the variable `disabled_rule_groups` should be optional. So if no disabled_rule_groups is set the block should be disabled. How can i achieve this? Do i need a second boolean variable and a if in the for each?

The best way to make the parameter optional is to allow it to default to an empty list. But the way you've written it, it already *is* optional, but when not specified, will default to the default you have written out.

Probably, what you want is this:

```hcl
variable "disabled_rule_groups" {
  default = []
}
```

Then, you don't need any conditional logic, because if you loop over an empty list (i.e. `for_each = []`) then none of those dynamic nested blocks will be generated, and that appears to be what you want.

Comment: @alex Harvey, the variable is not list, in fact it is nest with list and map. v0.12 supports more types now. https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#type-constraints

Comment: @BMW those type constraints are optional and the OP hasn’t asked about them or indicated any desire to use them so I am not sure it is relevant here unless I’m missing something?